# Python script that is suposed to change modifiers input value seem to change the value but has no effect on geometry

Tags: python, geometry, blender

Why it reads correct value. and even sorta updates it to print. but it has no effect to output or  when blend file is saved?

```
import bpy
import os

# Get the current directory where the script is located
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

# Set the blend file name to open
blend_file = os.path.join(script_dir, "T1.blend")

# Open the blend file
bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=blend_file)

object_name = "Cube"

cube_object = bpy.data.objects.get(object_name)

print(cube_object.modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Input_3"])

cube_object.modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Input_3"]=5

print(cube_object.modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Input_3"])


# Set the output STL file path
output_file = os.path.join(script_dir, "output.stl")

# Select all objects in the scene
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')

# Export selected objects as STL
bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath=output_file, use_selection=True)

# Print a message indicating success
print(f"Exported the scene as {output_file}")
'''
# Save the Blender file
save_path = blend_file 
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=save_path)
```

Updating scene has no effect.

```
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
```

changing default value of geometry node.. that chatgpt all the time suggests also has no effect..